# Does creating/closing a cursor in "mysql-connector-python" do anything with MySql?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

Im using the mysql-connector-python library for a script I wrote to access a MySql 8 Database:

```py
def get_document_by_id(conn,id):
    cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
    try:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id = %s",(id,))
        return cursor.fetchone()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        return {}
    finally:
        cursor.close()
```

Since i need to call this function multiple times during a loop, I was wondering about the following:

Does the act of creating/closing a cursor actually interact with my MySql-Database in any way or is it just used as an abstraction in python for grouping together SQL queries?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Not sure I understand when you run the code the result of the sql statement in the cursor.excute will be stored in the cursor when you close the cursor the data in the cursor will be discarded

Comment: Sorry if iam not clear.

I guess im asking if when i call "conn.cursor()", is there also a something happening on my MySql-Database? Like does it also create some sort of cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-close.html) says that clearly

> For a connection obtained from a connection pool, close() does not
> actually close it but returns it to the pool and makes it available
> for subsequent connection requests.

You can also refer to [Connector/Python Connection Pooling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html) for further information.